# Could not run Android app (Application stopped unexpectedly)

Tags: android, android-logcat

I am working on Building up Android Music Player app. I finished designing and coding but when i run it in Emulator it gives me following error :

**The application Droid Player (process com.droid.droidplayer) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.**

Here is the source code link:
[Source code](http://www.4shared.com/rar/DiSPXwq6/DroidPlayer.html)

There are no errors in source code but after running the app it shows errors in LogCat:

> 02-14 20:28:49.037: E/AndroidRuntime(383): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 02-14 20:28:49.037: E/AndroidRuntime(383): java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.droid.droidplayer/com.droid.droidplayer.Player}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> 02-14 20:28:49.037: E/AndroidRuntime(383): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1815)
>
> 02-14 20:28:49.037: E/AndroidRuntime(383): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
>
> 02-14 20:28:49.037: E/AndroidRuntime(383): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
>
> 02-14 20:28:49.037: E/AndroidRuntime(383): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
>
> 02-14 20:28:49.037: E/AndroidRuntime(383): at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>
> 02-14 20:28:49.037: E/AndroidRuntime(383): at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
>
> 02-14 20:28:49.037: E/AndroidRuntime(383): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
>
> 02-14 20:28:49.037: E/AndroidRuntime(383): at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 02-14 20:28:49.037: E/AndroidRuntime(383): at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
>
> 02-14 20:28:49.037: E/AndroidRuntime(383): at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
>
> 02-14 20:28:49.037: E/AndroidRuntime(383): at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
>
> 02-14 20:28:49.037: E/AndroidRuntime(383): at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> 02-14 20:28:49.037: E/AndroidRuntime(383): Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> 02-14 20:28:49.037: E/AndroidRuntime(383): at
>   com.droid.droidplayer.SongsManager.getPlayList(SongsManager.java:25)
>
> 02-14 20:28:49.037: E/AndroidRuntime(383): at
>   com.droid.droidplayer.Player.onCreate(Player.java:76)
>
> 02-14 20:28:49.037: E/AndroidRuntime(383): at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
>
> 02-14 20:28:49.037: E/AndroidRuntime(383): at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
>
> 02-14 20:28:49.037: E/AndroidRuntime(383): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
>
> 02-14 20:28:49.037: E/AndroidRuntime(383): ... 11 more
>
> 02-14 20:29:27.166: I/Process(383): Sending signal. PID: 383 SIG: 9

Comment: What is at line 25 of `SongsManager`? Its null

Comment: Add your SongsManager.java to this post and include line numbers. That will help.

Comment: @RotaryHeart

http://www.4shared.com/rar/DiSPXwq6/DroidPlayer.html
this link has full source code.

Answer (score 0):

An object at line 25 of your SongsManager is null.

Comment: I am very bad in writing java code so please help me in completing this.

Answer (score 0):

1. package com.droid.droidplayer;
2. 
3. import java.io.File;
4. import java.io.FilenameFilter;
5. import java.util.ArrayList;
6. import java.util.HashMap;
7. 
8. public class SongsManager {
9. // SDCard Path
10. final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/sdcard/");
11. private ArrayList> songsList = new ArrayList>();
12. 
13. // Constructor
14. public SongsManager(){
15. 
16. }
17. 
18. 
19. 
20. 
21. 
22. public ArrayList> getPlayList(){
23. File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
24. 
25. if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) {
26. for (File file : home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) {
27. HashMap song = new HashMap();
28. song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0 (file.getName().length() - 4)));
29. song.put("songPath", file.getPath());
30. 
31. // Adding each song to SongList
32. songsList.add(song);
33. }
34. }
35. // return songs list array
36. return songsList;
37. }
38. 
39. 
40. 
41. 
42. class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
43. public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
44. return (name.endsWith(".mp3") || name.endsWith(".MP3"));
45. }
46. }
47. }